# Strange ugettext_lazy and unicode behaviour

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding

I have been having a strange encoding issue with `ugettext_lazy` lately and I can't figure out what's happening.

I have a basic form:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label=_(u"Username"))
    ...
```

In my case, "Username" translates to "Nom d'utilisateur" but when I render the label I get the character code instead of the apostrophe.

One solution I found is to use `force_text` on `_(u"Username")` but clearly I shouldn't have to do that. Using `ugettext` instead of `ugettext_lazy` also works but isn't what I want.

I didn't change Django's default charset and my HTML file is using utf-8.

I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.5.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: What encoding do your message files use?

Comment: The [Django documentation on message files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files) states you *must* use UTF-8. Make sure your message files comply.